# How to migrate hudson jobs to Jenkins 1.6xx

Tags: jenkins, build, hudson, jenkins-plugins

What is the best way to migrate Hudson jobs to Jenkins?

When I tried to

1. copy job directory along with config.xml
2. reload configuration

its not showing up all the parameters and and build steps.
Could you help with best approach with minimal post migration fix?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can also check these very similar questions (this one is de-facto duplicate, or is the target Jenkins mentioned somewhat specific?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34269050/import-hudson-jobs-to-jenkins, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718437/hudson-to-jenkins-migration

Answer (score 0):

wrote shell script to copy parameters and build step from hudson config.xml to jenkins > config.xml and create new directory under jenkins and reload configuration thru scripting.

However, we had only couple of jobs with downstream/upstream. I didn't extend the script to automate this